# why a non generic derived type must specify the type parameter for a generic base class C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In Pro C# by Andrew Tolson, the writer says that when a non generic class extends a generic base class, the derived class must specify the type parameter.

```
// Assume you have created a custom
// generic list class.
public class MyList<T>
{
  private List<T> listOfData = new List<T>();
}
// Non-generic classes must specify the type
// parameter when deriving from a
// generic base class.
public class MyStringList : MyList<string>
{}
```

What I don't understand is why this is necessary?

Comment: Without explicitly specifying type parameter in derived class how's compiler supposed to guess what is the type of `T`?

Comment: What would you propose as an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, non-generic classes do not have type parameters, and generic classes have one or more type parameter.

If you inherit the class from a generic class, without specifying the type parameter, you still have a generic class, i.e

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T> {} //MyList is still generic
```

but

```
public class MyList : List<T> {} //invalid declaration, what is T ?
```

so

```
public class MyStringList : List<string> {} //specified with string
```

or, more general

```
public class MyArrayList : List<object> {} //specified with object
```

---

A more wordy explanation, mostly because I love using the word "[arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity)".

Classes in the CLR can have arity of zero or more, meaning that they can specify zero or more type parameters. However, the CLR cannot instantiate classes with non-zero arity, so in order to do anything useful, the arity of the class must be brought down to zero.

That means, that while we can partially specify classes like:

```
public class IntKeyDictionary<TValue> : Dictionary<int, TValue>
```

that decrease the arity, or even declare classes like

```
public class ListAndAHalf<TOne, TTwo> : List<TOne>
```

that increase the arity, the story has to end with a class with an arity of 0, like `List<string>`, `Dictionary<int, double>` etc...

Answer (score 7):

Because otherwise it's not a usable type because the CLR still doesn't know which type to use for `T`.

`List<T>` is an **open** type because `T` has not yet been substituted with an instantiable type. And you cannot create instances of open types. You can only create an instance of a type when it's **closed**, i.e. when all of its type parameters (that includes enclosing types and base types) have been replaced by instantiable types.

If you would be able to declare `class MyTList : MyList<T> { }`, then you would never have the possibility to specify a type for `T`, because `MyTList` doesn't include that type parameter anymore, thus you could never instantiate `MyTList`. That wouldn't be a very useful class.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't specify the type then the only other option is to make the derived class generic as well.

```
public class MyDerivedList<T> : MyList<T>
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What if it wasn't?

Your `MyStringList` would be generic (as there wouldn't be hardcoded type for `T`), but it's not by definition, as you build a non-generic class.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it the other way around. If you *didn't* specify the type parameter for your base type, what type *should* `MyList<T>` use? It will still be undefined.

You can create a generic type that inherits from another generic type, and then you don't have to specify the supertype's type parameter; your clients can do it.

Comment: You do still need to specify the base class's type parameter, but you can do so in terms of your own type parameter.